# Getting trigger properties in Quartz.NET

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I need to be able to get the properties (i.e. cron expression or type of simple trigger (daily, hourly, etc) and it's parameters) of a trigger in C#, and display them and also let them be modified. I have this right now:

```
Trigger[] trigger = sched.GetTriggersOfJob(id, groupid);
```

But I can't find any methods to let me access this information. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about

```
Trigger[] triggers = sched.GetTriggersOfJob(id, groupid);
foreach (SimpleTrigger simpleTrigger in triggers.OfType<SimpleTrigger>())
{
   //extract simple trigger info
}

foreach (CronTrigger cronTrigger in triggers.OfType<CronTrigger>())
{
  //extract cron trigger info
}
```

If efficiency is important, you can also do this in one loop:

```
Trigger[] triggers = sched.GetTriggersOfJob(id, groupid);
foreach (var trigger in triggers)
{
   SimpleTrigger simpleTrigger = trigger as SimpleTrigger;
   if (simpleTrigger != null)
   {
     //handle simple trigger
     continue;
   }
   //same for CronTrigger...
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, it's telling me that 'No overload for OfType takes 1 arguements' though

Comment: @Chris My mistake, it should work now. The more efficient solution should work anyway though.

Comment: Awesome, thanks :) one other, probably dumb issue - how do I go about extracting the trigger info? The trigger variable doesn't give me any more options for accessing the type of simple trigger, cron expression etc

Comment: The variable has all you need, I've edited the code to make it more apparent. whatever info you need can be gotten at: http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/topic604.html and http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/topic286.html